# how to set parameter into native query between single quotation in java hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

Below is the simple example which explain my problem

```
Query(name = "select p.* , pr.actual_date_time , count(*) " +
"from player p  " +
"inner join app.player_reports pr ON pr.player_id = p.id " +
"where pr.actual_date_time between  now() - interval '?1 day' 
   and now() - interval '0 day' " ,nativeQuery = true)
List<PlayerEntity> findCheaters(@param("NumberDays") int number )
```

this is my query, I want to put "NumberDays" between single quotation and substitute with "?1".

I would be glad to help me, and thank you

Comment: You can't use a parameter inside `interval` I believe.

Comment: do you have any idea how to do this query?

Comment: You would need to use a date function which accepts a pure numeric parameter.  Then, we could make it work.

Comment: got it gonna try this way to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't parametrize the value for the interval constant, but you can simply multiply the base unit with a parameter:

```
pr.actual_date_time between  now() - (interval '1 day' * ?) and now()
```

Then pass the number of days you want as an integer to the PreparedStatement.

---

Note that the `- interval '0 day'` is useless

Comment: so I should pass the query a String ?

Comment: No, an integer: the number of days.